# How to wrap ProcessPoolExecutor to make it allowing non-daemonic processes

Tags: multiprocessing, daemon, concurrent.futures

In my use case, I need to run ProcessPoolExecutor inside ProcessPoolExecutor, so it'd be very convenient to allow ProcessPoolExecutor to have non-daemonic processes.

I am wondering to how change this behavior with minimal modification by wrapping ProcessPoolExecutor ?

-----------Update-------------------

My use case is in machine learning, where we parallelize the experiments with different hyperparameter settings with outer ProcessPoolExecutor and the algorithm itself also parallelized with inner ProcessPoolExecutor.

a toy psedo-code looks like

```py
def algo(config):
    candidates = make_candidates(...)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(evaluation, candidates)

configs = make_configs(...)
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(algo, configs)
```

Comment: could you post some code to motivate this use case? it sounds somewhat misguided at the moment!  why not just evaluate things using the appropriate (outer) executor?

Comment: @SamMason Thanks for the comment. The use case I have now is in machine learning experiments, and a toy code example with explanation is added in the post.

Comment: just realised that looks a bit like a fork bomb to me!  the outer executor will allocate nCPUs worth of processes, and then each inner executor will do the same.  I think you're better off refactoring your code, or maybe using something higher level that can handle this use case better.  especially as you're probably using numeric libraries that will also be spawning lots of threads to do large array ops faster